# How to use 2 variables with for condition?

Tags: bash, for-loop, syntax, terminal

I just got some photos from a friend.
Input:

```
'WhatsApp Image 2020-01-03 at 15.13.36.jpeg'      
'WhatsApp Image 2020-01-03 at 15.13.37.jpeg'
'WhatsApp Image 2020-01-03 at 15.13.37 (1).jpeg'  
'WhatsApp Image 2020-01-03 at 15.13.38.jpeg'
```

I would like to change their names with some kind of automation. So i know that when i write:

```
for x in ./*.jpeg;do open $x;done
```

I can open all files within the same directory. 
To change their names can i use the command:

```
mv a.jpeg b.jpeg
```

So my question is how to write an for loop, so that i not only change the name but also increment some val number:
This must looks some like:

```
i=1 && for x in ./*.jpeg;do mv ./$x ./$i.jpeg & i++; done
```

I'm not sure how would the appropriate syntax would looks like.

Input:

```
'WhatsApp Image 2020-01-03 at 15.13.36.jpeg'      
'WhatsApp Image 2020-01-03 at 15.13.37.jpeg'
'WhatsApp Image 2020-01-03 at 15.13.37 (1).jpeg'  
'WhatsApp Image 2020-01-03 at 15.13.38.jpeg'
```

Output:

```
1.jpeg
2.jpeg
3.jpeg
4.jpeg
```

Comment: please leave an example of the input and output files. thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use `&` as a boolean `and` operator?  You want `&&`.

Comment: does it have to be a one liner?

Comment: You are right. It should be &&. One line would be a pleasure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i=1; for x in *.jpeg; do mv -i "$x" "$((i++)).jpeg"; done
```